# Org Mode tangle comment

Tags: emacs, org-mode

with this line in a file i'm tangling:

```
  #+BEGIN_SRC shell :tangle ./tangle/aux.0 :comments link :paddling no
```

on tangling, this prompt appears:

```
   "No comment syntax is define.  Use: [ ]"
```

What needs to be set, or text entered in the source file to avoid the prompt?

I've tried:

```
# <<example>>
```

or
    #
on the first line.

or   ... comment-syntax #

after the ":comments link" 
and searched the help for examples.

I'm reading the Org Manual, and emacs help, and not finding any specific instructions.

Comment: make that ":padline no", which raised the question:  in a code forum, how to defeat the gratuitous spell-checking corrections?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is because emacs cannot determine/recognise the correct mode for the exported source. As it does not recognise the mode, it cannot determine the correct comment character.

According the the org manual, the correct identifier for shell blocks is sh not shell. Try changing your line to

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :tangle ./tangle/aux.0 :comments link :paddling no
```

Comment: thanks.  that was it.  & I thought I'd ruled that out.   "sh"  is it.  and it's still "padline"

Comment: Do you mean that the comment is being pushed over to the right? If so, this is probably due to the default setting for comment-column in sh mode.  Normally, org-bable will strip leading indent off comments (see org-babel-process-comment-test for details). I tried your example and it worked fine for me - comments were at the left column.

Comment: Are we talking about tangling or exporting?